# How do i get the auto id from entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am wanting to get the id of the customer i just created to insert into the userId table this will be filled with information contained in a lookup table.

My question is how do i retreive the id from the newewly created customer. I am using entity framework 6 btw

```
tblPortalCustomerInfo _customer = new tblPortalCustomerInfo();

_customer.firstName = firstname;
_customer.middleName = middle;
_customer.lastName = lastname;
_customer.IVACODE = ivaCode;
_customer.email = emailAddress;

portalEntities.tblPortalCustomerInfoes.Add(_customer);

tblPortalUser _user = new tblPortalUser();
_user.customerInfo = _customer.id; this is where i need the link?.
_user.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
_user.password = password;
_user.isActive = true;
_user.optinDateStart = DateTime.Now;

portalEntities.tblPortalUsers.Add(_user);
portalEntities.tblPortalUsers.Add(_user);
```

Comment: You have to add the user first, and save it. Only then will you be able to get the ID (if the table is auto incremented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert that customer row first, and then it will autmoatically get populated with primary key value in `_customer.id` generated for it like:

```
tblPortalCustomerInfo _customer = new tblPortalCustomerInfo();

_customer.firstName = firstname;
_customer.middleName = middle;
_customer.lastName = lastname;
_customer.IVACODE = ivaCode;
_customer.email = emailAddress;

portalEntities.tblPortalCustomerInfoes.Add(_customer);
portalEntities.SaveChanges(); // insert the customer


tblPortalUser _user = new tblPortalUser();
_user.customerInfo = _customer.id; // now you should have primary key value here
_user.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
_user.password = password;
_user.isActive = true;
_user.optinDateStart = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan your becoming quite well known on the form mate, i thougth it would have been someothing as silly as that

Answer (score 1):

You need to call SaveChange() method after add a new record, then you will get the new generated ID